# Erro ao atribuir contexto de função nativa

Tags: javascript

Ao usar o código:

```
let _  = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let __ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

Eu informo o contexto onde `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll` serão chamados.

Porém quando chamo eles de forma sequencial, por exemplo:

```
let steps = _(".wizard-steps").__("li.nav-item");
```

Recebo o erro:

> _(...).__ is not a function

Quando chamo dessa forma funciona:

```
let steps = _(".wizard-steps").querySelectorAll("li.nav-item");
```

Tentei:

```
let _  = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let __ = _.bind(_);
```

Mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro temos que entender o que `bind` faz. Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> *creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value*

Ou seja, o `bind` cria uma nova função que, quando chamada, tem o `this` setado para o valor que foi informado. Então quando você faz:

```
let _ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let __ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

Está dizendo que `_` sempre chamará `document.querySelector`, e `__` sempre chamará `document.querySelectorAll`.

Por isso `_('alguma coisa')` funciona, pois é como se você chamasse `document.querySelector('alguma coisa')`. Mas o [retorno desta função](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Return_value) é um [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), que não possui o método `__` (lembre-se que `__` foi definido como uma função que chama `document.querySelectorAll`).

Uma solução para fazer o que você quer seria definir `__` no *prototype* de `HTMLElement`, fazendo-o apontar para o método desejado (no caso, `querySelectorAll`):

```js
let _  = document.querySelector.bind(document);
HTMLElement.prototype.__ = HTMLElement.prototype.querySelectorAll;

_('#abc').__('span').forEach(s => console.log(s.innerText));
```

```html
<p id="abc">
  Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor <span>sit</span> amet.
</p>
```

Assim, `_` continua chamando `document.querySelector`, mas `__` chama o `querySelectorAll` do `HTMLElement` retornado por `_`.

---

Claro que você pode manter as duas opções (tanto no `document` quanto no *prototype*):

```js
let _  = document.querySelector.bind(document);
let __  = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
HTMLElement.prototype._ = HTMLElement.prototype.querySelector;
HTMLElement.prototype.__ = HTMLElement.prototype.querySelectorAll;

__('span').forEach(s => console.log(s._('a').innerText));

_('#abc').__('span').forEach(s => console.log(s.innerText));
```

```html
<p id="abc">
  Lorem <span>ipsum <a href="">link1</a></span> dolor <span>sit <a href="">link2</a></span> amet.
</p>
```

Assim, quando `_` ou `__` forem chamados diretamente, estarão chamando os métodos de `document`, e quando forem chamados no resultado destes, estarão chamando os métodos dos respectivos `HTMLElement`'s.

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelector.bind()` retorna um `HTMLElement` conforme a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Existem pelo menos dois métodos `querySelectorAll()` disponíveis, [o que manipula um documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) e [o que manipula um elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

Quando aplica O `_` (odeio esses nomes que são dispensáveis) ele retorna um elemento e portanto o `querySelectorAll()` a ser chamado é o do [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) já que é a mãe de `HTMLElement`.

Quando usa o `__` está usando o método do documento em cima de **um objeto que é um elemento** (lembra do retorno do `_`?). Não dá certo.

Eu não fiz testes do que poderia funcionar, mas a explicação porque isso não dá certo está aí. Eu acho que tem que chamar o `HTMLElement` ou `Element` diretamente e não o documento.